# C++ Division of double

Tags: c++, double, division

I'realy don't understand how divide doubles in c++ and have the correct precision.

I read many posts and undertood the logic ([What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)) but I dont see how I can do. Could you help me :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //Convert 123 minutes in hh:mm

    double a(123); //Minutes in decimal format
    
    double resultat = a/60.0;

    //resultat = 2.0499999999999998 and not 2.05
    double hours;
    double decimalMinute;
    
    decimalMinute = modf(resultat, &hours);
    
    int minutes = decimalMinute*60.0;
    //Give 2 and not 3 !!!

    double minutesDouble = decimalMinute*60.0;
    //Give 2,999999 and not 3 !!

    return 0;
}
```

How can I have the "correct" value ?

Comment: the values are "correct"

Comment: if you want precise results do not use floating point numbers. In your example fixed point numbers with 2 decimals are sufficient to get precise results

Comment: *I dont see how I can do* - hint: you don't need floating point math in your example. Integer division and integer modulo is what you need.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/f7j5chjGq

Comment: You didn't understand the logic.

Comment: Thank @463035818_is_not_a_number for your feed back.

I don't want use ``std::out`` but use the result. If i add the code bellow, I always have error because minutesDouble is not equal to 3. What can I do ? 
``if (minutesDouble != double(3.0)){
        std::cout << "Erreur : " << minutesDouble;
    } else {
        std::cout << "OK";
    }``

@Yksisarvinen : Hour & minutes are only an example. This conversion is not my goal.

Comment: what i already said: If you need exact numbers, do not use floating point numbers. Why is `minutesDouble` a `double` at all? `123 % 3` is `3` exact